# Valid number of array formations

Tags: arrays

How to go about solving a problem like this?

You are given two integers N and K. It is given that an array A is called valid if it satisfies the following condition:

1. Sum of elements of A is exactly N
2. K*A[i] >= A[i+1]

Find the total number of valid arrays that can be formed. Since the answer can be large print it modulo 10^9+7.

For eg: if N=100 and K=3 then some of the arrays that can be formed are: [100], [24, 76], [1, 5, 22, 72] and so on..

I could not think of an optimized solution other than backtracking approach which might be unfeasible for a problem of this scale.
Could use any help I can get to understand the logic behind this problem.
Also is there any specific algorithm that can help solve questions of this kind?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this problem has a math answer, but I don't know, so I will use a programming approach to solve.

I call `m` is number of array elements, we have:

A[1] +   A[2] +     A[3] +     A[4] + ... +           A[m] = N

A[1] + K.A[1] + K^2.A[1] + K^3.A[1] + ... + K^(m - 1).A[1] = N

Call `A[1]` is `x`, we have:

x + xK + xK^2 + xK^3 + ... + xK^(m - 1) = N

1 + K + K^2 + ... + K^(m-1)       = N/x

K + K^2 + K^3 + ...     + K^m = N/x * K

K^m - 1 = N/x.(K-1)

x = N / [(K-1)(K^m-1)]

As we can see, there are 2 variables need to be found: `m` & `x`. Both `m` & `x` are integer type. Therefore, use `while` loop with `m` starts from 1 until boundary `N / [(K-1)(K^m-1)] < 1`. If the division `N / [(K-1)(K^m-1)]` is an integer, you found a properly result. Just count it.

Hope that's right.